# What's the difference between the environments quote and quotation?

Tags: environments, quoting

On meta, I've found the disscussion [{quotation} and {quote}](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/934/quotation-and-quote), but it doesn't answer my question.

When should I use the environment `quote`? When `quotation`?

Comment: The meta thread is about the tags with this names, used on this site, not the LaTeX environments.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I just linked it, because it says there "hey are different, though closely related".

Answer (score 168, accepted):

The worth reading [LaTeX Wiki Book](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Formatting#Quoting_text) describes the differences as follows:

> - **`quote`** for a short quotation, or a series of small quotes, separated by blank lines.
> - **`quotation`** for use with longer quotations, of more than one paragraph, because it indents the first line of each paragraph.

And in addition to the above:

> - **`verse`** is for quotations where line breaks are important, such as poetry. Once in, new stanzas are created with a blank line, and new lines within a stanza are indicated using the newline command, `\\`. If a line takes up more than one line on the page, then all subsequent lines are indented until explicitly separated with `\\`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! If it's a longer quotation with only one paragraph you would recommend quote, though? (since there would be only the first line indented)

Comment: Hm, would be a matter of personal taste, I guess. Since the whole quote block is indented anyway I, personally, would most likely use `quote`.

Answer (score 77):

The technical difference between both environments can be best seen from their definitions (done in the standard class files, e.g. `article.cls` lines 486-496):

```
\newenvironment{quotation}
               {\list{}{\listparindent 1.5em%
                        \itemindent    \listparindent
                        \rightmargin   \leftmargin
                        \parsep        \z@ \@plus\p@}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
\newenvironment{quote}
               {\list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
```

As you can see, both use a `list` environment and set the right margin to be equal to the left margin, which produces the indentation on *both* sites (for a reason I don't fully understand myself).

In addition to that, `quotation` also sets

- `\listparindent` to 1.5em 
  ("extra indentation at beginning of every paragraph of a list except
  the one started by the `\item` command."),
- `\itemindent` to `\listparindent` ("extra indentation added right BEFORE an item label.") and
- `\parsep` to `0pt plus 1pt` (separation between paragraphs).

(Descriptions taken from [`source2e`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/doc/source2e.pdf))

This means that several indentions are done differently, which, AFAIK, seems to be important for longer quotations.

Comment: Nice answer, it's always enlightening to see how things are defined. Perhaps you could add a sentence or two how and from where you retrieved these definitions, so that users can learn how to find out such things by themselves?

Answer (score 31):

In my opinion, the side-by side existence of `quotation` and `quote` is a bad design decision of LaTeX's initial developer Leslie Lamport. I have written the [`quoting`](http://ctan.org/pkg/quoting) package that provides the environment of the same name, a consolidated environment for displayed text. With `quoting`, first-line indentation is activated by adding a blank line before the environment.

What's exactly bad about `quotation` and `quote` in their present form? Quoting from the `quoting` documentation:

> - The `quotation` environment isn't suited for documents which use vertical spacing instead of indentation to denote the start of new
>     paragraphs. If one retroactively adopts such a layout, one should
>     change the definition of `\quotation` and `\endquotation` to `\quote`
>     resp. `\endquote`.
> - The side-by-side existence of two environments for displayed text narrows the utility of the `csquotes` package which provides
>     higher-level wrapper environments, e.g. for quoting in a foreign
>     language and specifying the source of citations. Currently, `csquotes`
>     uses `quote` as a backend environment, but with LaTeX's default
>     settings, this is not appropriate for multi-paragraph quotes.

Should you want *"a series of small quotes"* (the alternative, though rather infrequent use of `quote`), you may string together several instances of the `quoting` environment (depending on your indentation preferences, with or without blank lines between them).

Comment: @wchargin AFAIK, competition of standards usually involves financial interests. After viewing the comic, I first upvoted this comment, but soon I realized that it was not good to discourage the effort to polish LaTeX2e and canceled my upvote of this comment. If we take packages fixing pitfalls of LaTeX2e in some scenario as redundant, just like alternative standards, then many packages trying to fix pitfalls of LaTeX2e from LaTeX3 team would be redundant too. Also, built-in document classes do have pitfalls, and such pitfalls leads to the popularity of `koma-script` and `memoir`.

Comment: @Eli4ph: I'm a bit confused. What comment? I don't see a comment by me in this thread, but neither have I deleted a comment or used this site at all in the last 12 hours. What did I say? :-)

Comment: ‘Quoting from the `quoting` documentation’ – nice.

Comment: @wchargin I'm almost certain that he's referring to XKCD Comic #927 "Standards", that I guess some other comment that was deleted referenced?