# Change margins of quotation environment asymmetrically

Tags: indentation, quoting, mla-style

I need to write an essay in MLA style and have a block quotation consisting of two paragraphs. I found a way to keep the indentation of the first line of each paragraph intact by following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2461/60686). Redefining the `quotation` environment with the code proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2430/60686) kills the additional indentation of the first line in each paragraph – this seems to be a variation on the definition for `quote`, compare [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33222/60686) for definitions of both the `quote` and the `quotation` environment.

Using `etoolbox`'s `\patchcmd` the way it's being used [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2461/60686) produces a margin of the same width on either side of the quotation, while I only need the `quotation` environment to be indented by 1 inch on the left side. Also, the indentation of the first line of each paragraph needs to be a quarter inch wide according to MLA. How can I do those things? Is it advisable to use `etoolbox` in that case at all?

`\renewenvironment` with the code for `quotation` used [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33222/60686) unfortunately returns an error:

```
l.190 \begin{quotation}

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...n \leftmargin \parsep \z @ \@plus\p 
                                                  @
```

Working example (minimal?!):

```
\documentclass{article}

% Ragged right text and paragraph indentation 0.5in
\raggedright
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\quotation}{\rightmargin}{\leftmargin 1in \rightmargin}{}{}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque.

\begin{quotation}
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat.

Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus.
\end{quotation}

Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.

\end{document}
```

This results in:

[image: Result of MWE]

What I want, however, is something like this:

[image: What it should look like]

Comment: Your renewenvironment with the code for quotation in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33222/60686 is probably not in a *.cls, *.clo or *.sty file, hence you should put it between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. A MWE will help us, if we are guessing correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be to define your own environment for this, emulating the `adjustwidth` environment from [`changepage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% Ragged right text and paragraph indentation 0.5in
\raggedright
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}

\usepackage{changepage}

\newenvironment{myquotation}[1][1in]
  {\par\vspace{\topsep}%
   \begin{adjustwidth}{#1}{0pt}
   \setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}% Similar to quotation
   \leavevmode\hspace*{\parindent}\ignorespaces}
  {\end{adjustwidth}
   \vspace{\topsep}}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\quotation}{\rightmargin}{\leftmargin 1in \rightmargin}{}{}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque.

\begin{quotation}
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat.

Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus.
\end{quotation}

Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque.

\begin{myquotation}
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat.

Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus.
\end{myquotation}

Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.

\end{document}
```

The above example defines `myquotation` with an optional argument (defaults to `1in`) for the left margin/indentation. Since the `adjustwidth` environment typically sets the first paragraph without indentation, a forced `\hspace*{\parindent}` is placed to simulate this.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, your custom environment can be defined using my [`quoting`](http://ctan.org/pkg/quoting) package and its key-value options. To specify a paragraph indentation that is different from that of the surrounding text, use the `\AtBeginEnvironment` macro provided by `etoolbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\raggedright
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}

\usepackage[indentfirst=true,leftmargin=1in,rightmargin=0pt]{quoting}

% \usepackage{etoolbox}% already loaded by 'quoting' 
\AtBeginEnvironment{quoting}{%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0.25in}%
}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque.

\begin{quoting}
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat.

Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus.
\end{quoting}

Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.

\end{document}
```

[image]