# Single-spaced equations in double-spaced documents

Tags: spacing, equations, setspace

My university guidelines (unfortunately) mandate double-spacing. However, nothing is said about double-spacing equations, so I'd like to **print equations single-spaced**. Easy enough:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[doublespacing,nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{align*}{\begin{singlespace}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{align*}{\end{singlespace}\noindent\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{align*}
  Abc = DEF\\
  DEF = Abc
\end{align*}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

This is inspired by @GonzaloMedina's answer on [Equations and Double Spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49880/equations-and-double-spacing).  Unfortunately, it doesn't work:

[image: too much space]

The problem is that the space before the equation is greater than the space after it.  What gives?

Comment: Possibly related: [Uneven spacing around blockquote](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/306168).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`singlespace` starts a new `\par`. Add a negative \baselineskip:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[doublespacing,nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{align*}{\begin{singlespace}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{align*}{\end{singlespace}\noindent\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{align*}
  Abc = DEF \\
  DEF = Abc
\end{align*}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Surprisingly, however, this breaks `\[` `\]`... That is, if I add the same code for `equation*`, then the spacing above `\[` is wrong.

Comment: More precisely, the `singlespace` environment terminates the current paragraph, if any, and forces vertical mode.  It is the displayed equation that, at this point, begins a new (partial) paragraph, consisting of a single line that contains only the indentation box.  See _The TeXbook_, answer to Exercise 14.30, on p. 316, last three lines.

Comment: +1. It would be great if an option like this was built into setspace (or the memoir class, which is what I am using), instead of having to do this for every type of displayed math environment I use.

Comment: instead of `align*` can I use `equation`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a patch that works in the same way in `align*`, `gather*`, and `equation*`.  For detailed explanations, see *The TeXbook*, pages 188–189; here suffice it to say that the different behavior doesn’t arise from the vertical backspace, but from the choice of `\abovedisplayskip` versus `\abovedisplayshortskip`.  I apologize in advance for my inclination to prefer raw TeX primitives over higher level constructs…

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[doublespacing,nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\MySingleSpacePatch{%
    \begin{singlespace}%
    \vskip -\baselineskip
    \noindent
    \dimen@ \hsize
    \advance \dimen@ \p@
    \hskip \dimen@ \@minus \tw@\p@ % 2pt and not 1pt because I am paranoid
    \null
}
\newcommand*\EndMySingleSpacePatch{%
    \end{singlespace}%
    \noindent\ignorespaces
}

\makeatother

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{equation*}{\MySingleSpacePatch}
\AfterEndEnvironment{equation*}{\EndMySingleSpacePatch}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{gather*}{\MySingleSpacePatch}
\AfterEndEnvironment{gather*}{\EndMySingleSpacePatch}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{align*}{\MySingleSpacePatch}
\AfterEndEnvironment{align*}{\EndMySingleSpacePatch}



\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{align*}
    x&=y+1 \\
    a&=b
\end{align*}
\lipsum*[4]

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{gather*}
    x=y \\
    a=b
\end{gather*}
\lipsum*[4]

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation*}
  DEF = Abc
\end{equation*}
\lipsum*[4]

% \showboxbreadth = 10000
% \showboxdepth = 10
% \showlists

\end{document}
```