# Inline math with double spacing

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I am using this [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/324095/46385) by Bernard to have equations in display mode appear single-spaced in a double-spaced document.
How can I achieve a similar result for inline math?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[doublespacing,nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{align*}{\begin{singlespace}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{align*}{\end{singlespace}\noindent\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{align*}
  Abc = DEF \\
  DEF = Abc
\end{align*}
\lipsum[2]

Inline math: $\mqty(x\\y)$ 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to set `\jot` to a negative dimension. Next, you can set `\arraystretch` to the reciprocal of `\baselinestretch`, which will affect `array` based objects.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[
  doublespacing,
  nodisplayskipstretch
]{setspace}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\jot}{-4pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{align*}
  Abc = DEF \\
  DEF = Abc
\end{align*}
\lipsum[2]

Inline math: $\mqty(x\\y)$

\end{document}
```

Explanation: `amsmath` adds `\jot` to the interline spacing in its alignment environments.

[image]

Not that I endorse using `physics`; actually I recommend *not* using it.

If you want to also fix `cases`, load `etoolbox` and, in the document preamble, say

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\env@cases}{1.2}{0.72}{}{}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Why `0.72`? Because `\env@cases` does `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}`, but we actually want it to be `1.2` times `0.6`, which is the reciprocal of `1.667`, the value of `\baselinestretch` for `doublespacing`.

If `\onehalfspacing` is used, it corresponds to a value `1.25` of `\baselinestretch` and the reciprocal to use is `0.8`. For `cases` you need `0.96` instead of `0.72`.

Comment: Thanks!, How did you determine the -4pt and 0.6 numbers? should these change if I am actually using onehalfspacing and different font size?

Comment: Also, I think your solution has drawbacks when it comes to display math compared to Bernard's from the post I linked. For example, using \begin{cases} \end{cases} inside a \begin{equation} gives rise to double-spacing with your solution but not with Bernard's.

Comment: @user1830663 You also need to fix `cases`. Just don't worry: double spacing completely ruins a document, so why bother? Anyway, it's Bernard's solution that has drawbacks. I'll add the fix for `cases`.

Comment: Thesis style requirements... no choice

Comment: @user1830663 Try telling them we're in the 21st century.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Why -4pt in \setlength{\jot}{-4pt} ?

Comment: @user1830663 Visual determination.