# Right alignment of equation numbers in quotation

Tags: numbering

I use a quotation environment to make axioms or assumptions stand out from other text. But the equation numbers then end up at the right margin for the quotation environment, not the right margin of the text:

[image]

Question: How can I put the equation numbers from the quotation environment in the same place as the second equation number?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
Inside quotation environment:
\begin{quotation}
Axiom name:
\begin{equation}
a = b.
\end{equation}
\end{quotation}
Outside quotation environment:
\begin{equation}
c = d.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure that an equation inside `quotation` is the right way to use it?

Comment: I suggest the usage of a `theorem` like environment rather to emphasize axioms etc.

Comment: This is the preferred way for the journal I am writing for.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same trick as `amsart`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter % ams classes trick
\def\fullwidthdisplay{\displayindent\z@ \displaywidth\columnwidth}
\edef\@tempa{\noexpand\fullwidthdisplay\the\everydisplay}
\everydisplay\expandafter{\@tempa}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Inside quotation environment:
\begin{quotation}
Axiom name:
\begin{equation}
a = b.
\end{equation}
\end{quotation}
Outside quotation environment:
\begin{equation}
c = d.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The environment `abstract` is derived from `quotation` environment  [from egreg answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151589/54817)

```
\newenvironment{abstract}
 {\small
  \begin{center}
  \bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{0pt}
  \end{center}
  \quotation}
 {\endquotation}
```

The definition of `quotation` environment from `article.cls` [Martin Scharrer answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33222/54817)

```
 \newenvironment{quotation}
                   {\list{}{\listparindent 1.5em%
                            \itemindent    \listparindent
                            \rightmargin   \leftmargin
                            \parsep        \z@ \@plus\p@}%
                    \item\relax}
                   {\endlist}
```

You can for example put your equation inside `minipage` and shift it to the left with   `\hspace{-\leftmargin}`.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Inside quotation environment:

\begin{quotation}
Axiom name:

\noindent\hspace{-\leftmargin}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
c = d.
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}

\end{quotation}
Outside quotation environment:

\begin{equation}
c = d.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]